# Apache2 and domain name

Tags: apache, linux, apache2

I have a server running several sites (sites-available/...) which all have a domain name, and are differentiated using their port number(www.xxx.com:8090, www.xxx.com:8091,etc..) I have a domain name (i.e: blabla.com) which I want to set for only one of the sitesm so when I type: www.blabla.com it will go to that site.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 80 port for this site, no?